# Using Geometry by Expression tool to make set of lines in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, expression, polyline-creation, geometry-generator

In QGIS 3 I am trying to make a set of lines that are 50m to 2000m, at 50 meter intervals (e.g.: line 1 is 50m, line 2 is 100m, line 3 is 150m, etc).

I did it manually using the Advanced digitizing tool bar, but I would like to learn to do it more elegantly using the "Geometry by Expression" tool.

How do I use the "Geometry by Expression" tool to make a set of lines with a particular length interval using QGIS 3.x?

Comment: It might be simpler using the tool `Vector Creation / array of offset lines` or `Vector Creation / array of translated features`

Comment: I think that with the _Geometry by Expression_ algorithm you can return one output feature for each input feature. The output feature could contain a MultiLineString geometry, but overlapped parts make a non-[OGC simple](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) geometry. Seems to me better (and easier) perform that task with another method: a SQL query or a Python script. In any case: How would the starting point and azimuth be established?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from an original line (black), use the following expression with [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) to create lines with 50 m intervals (from 50 to 2000 m distance from the original line). This expression only generates lines **to the left** of the original line. To have lines on both sides, replace the first instance of `50` in line 3 by `-2000` (see screenshot):

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (50,2000,50),
        offset_curve( $geometry, @element)
    )
)
```

The result is a multipart geometry. Run `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Multipart to singleparts` to get individual lines.

*Screenshot, demonstrating the expression with Geometry generator: the red lines are created by the expression, based on the black line:*
[image]